# Error 304 Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) en django python con POST

Tags: python, django, rest

agradecería que me ayudaran con este inconveniente, estoy intentando hacer POST en django. este es el código que tengo de views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request, JsonResponse
from .models import Empleados
from django.views import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.decorators import APIView

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
# Create your views here.
def EmpleadoDetalles(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        obj = Empleados.objects.all()
        data = {"Response":list(obj.values("id","name","carrera","promedio"))}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST["name"]
        obj = Empleados(name = name)
        obj.save()
        data = {"response":{"id":obj.id,"name":obj.name,"carrera":obj.carrera,"promedio":obj.promedio}}
        return JsonResponse(data)

class ListEmpleados(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        obj = Empleados.objects.all()
        data = {"Response":list(obj.values("id","name","carrera","promedio"))}
        return JsonResponse(data)
    
    def post(self,request):
        name = request.POST["name"]
        obj = Empleados(name = name)
        obj.save()
        data = {"response":{"id":obj.id,"name":obj.name,"carrera":obj.carrera,"promedio":obj.promedio}}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Tengo dos urls, en detallesEmpleado puedo hacer GET el status es: 200 OK
cuando le hago POST a esa url la respuesta es 405(yo la puse así)
pero cuando hago POST a la url de ListEmpleados su respuesta es: 403 Forbidden

Literalmente estoy siguiendo un "proyecto guíado" de coursera, al inicio a ella le salió el error, el cuál solucióno añadiendo `@csrf_exempt` , pero a mi se me sigue presentando

Este es url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from my_app.views import EmpleadoDetalles,ListEmpleados

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('detallesEmpleado/', EmpleadoDetalles),
    path('listaEmpleado/',ListEmpleados.as_view)
]
```

Salida:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /listaEmpleado/
[23/Oct/2020 17:40:14] "POST /listaEmpleado/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

Les agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: ¿Hiciste alguna modificación en específico a los valores de configuración global de Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte solo le estas indicando que excluya el csrf en la petición GET

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
# Create your views here.
def EmpleadoDetalles(request):
```

intenta colocando

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
# Create your views here.
def EmpleadoDetalles(request):
```